# Create and append matrices in a loop using R

Tags: r, join, matrix, concatenation, append

I defined a function `matrix.create()` that generates a `m x n` Matrix and I'll use a loop to generate matrices for every `t = 100` timesteps. The result should be one big matrix of dimension `m*t x n`.

Is there an easy way to do this? Should I concatenate the matrices within the function?

Comment: What are the arguments of `matrix.create()`? i.e., does its output depend on `t` explicitly or implicitly (e.g. by passing the results of the previous call)?

Comment: It is a .rds file from which I extract the matrix values. The output does not depend on t.

Comment: so are there (say) 10,000 distinct matrices, or one matrix repeated 10,000 times?

Comment: 10,000 distinct matrices with different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how (one way) to avoid growing the matrix (inefficient: see e.g. [here](https://insightr.wordpress.com/2018/08/23/growing-objects-and-loop-memory-pre-allocation/) or chapter 2 [here](https://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/)) when every matrix is different:

```r
res <- list()
for(t in 1:n){
  res[[i]] <- matrix.create(...)
}
mat <- do.call("rbind", res)
```

Note that growing a list by appending objects (which is basically what we're doing here, although in an R-ish way) does **not** incur the same penalty as growing vectors, matrices, or data frames.

It might be *slightly* more efficient to do this:

```r
nr <- 10; nc <- 10 ## or whatever
mat <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = nr*n, ncol = nc)
ind <- 1
for (t in 1:n) {
   mat[ind:(ind+nr),] <- matrix.create(...)
   ind <- ind + nr
}
```

Instead of incrementing a current-index variable, you could also do this by computing the appropriate indices at each step (i.e., `((t-1)*nr + 1):(t*nr)`)

Answer (score 2):

One approach to avoid the loop:

```
## demo function (returns an n x m matrix of NAs)
create_matrix <- \(n, m) matrix(, n, m)
```

```
n = 1
m = 3
t = 4


do.call(rbind, replicate(t, create_matrix(n, m), simplify = FALSE))
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: This is nice - can I use this structure for matrices that contain different values?

Comment: Thank you. You can use it to `rbind` matrices of different values. Note, however, that values will be coerced to the same class: `rbind(matrix(1L), matrix(pi), matrix('a'))`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the contents of matrices returned by `matrix.create` look like, but perhaps this general example will help:

```
matrix.create <- function(m,n){
  
  return(matrix(NA,nrow = m,ncol = n))
  
}
mat <- matrix.create(m = 1,n = 2)
for(t in 2:100){
  mat <- rbind(mat,matrix.create(m = 1,n = 2))
}
mat
```

Comment: Best not to 'grow' matrices by successive `rbind`ing: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf chapter 2

Comment: That really only matters when we get into thousands or millions of iterations, not 100. I think my solution is adequate given the information provided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. t is going to be much larger (around 20000).

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, @I_O's answer is more appropriate. It matches the solution to the "growing object" problem discussed in R Inferno (page 14).

Comment: But this idea is good for small values of t!